# Issue with ASP.NET Core API tokens?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

I have built an API with ASP.Net Core 3.1, to be used with IIS as a reverse proxy to Kestrel (out of process).  I'm using an internal database for the authentication.  The API is working fine when run locally, but not on the IIS server.

The Postman error I get is:

> Error: connect ETIMEDOUT x.x.x.x:443
>   Warning: This request did not get sent completely and might not have all the required system headers

When running it locally, the token I get looks like this:

> {
>    alg: "HS512",
>    typ: "JWT"
>   }.
>   {
>    unique_name: "2",
>    nbf: 1588861522,
>    exp: 1588865122,
>    iat: 1588861522
>   }.
>   [signature]

On the server, I can run the app at the console and get results through IE, so I'm wondering if the issue may be with the JWT tokens, or possibly the MS-ASPNETCORE-TOKEN header that gets sent to Kestrel?  Is the MS-ASPNETCORE-TOKEN forwarding to Kestrel handled behind the scenes, or do I need to set that up?  Documentation leads me to believe that's all handled automatically.

The only error I've seen in logs (though I'm not getting it consistently) is:

> 'MS-ASPNETCORE-TOKEN' does not match the expected pairing token '88c68a82-4b24-4876-ad11-6f78238c8800', request rejected

Does anyone see what my issue may be?

Program.cs:

```
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseKestrel();
                webBuilder.UseIISIntegration();
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

Startup.cs:

```
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration));
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var connectionString = _configuration["connectionStrings:PecanDBConnectionString"];
        services.AddDbContext<PecanContext>(o =>
        {
            o.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        });

        //services.AddCors();
        services.AddControllers();
        services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
            options.ForwardClientCertificate = false;
        });

        //configure DI for application services
        services.AddScoped<IAccInfoRepository, AccInfoRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IAccPlantRepository, AccPlantRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IPlantLocationRepository, PlantLocationRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<INutQualityRepository, NutQualityRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IPlantImageRepository, PlantImageRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();

        services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

        //configure strongly typed settings objects
        var appSettingsSection = _configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);

        //configure jwt authentication
        var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);
        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            };
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");

            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
                {
                await next();
                if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
                {
                    context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
                    await next();
                }
            });
            //app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
```